# Python SubTest Parameters

Tags: python, python-unittest

When using python's unittest [subtest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests), I am confused regarding how parameters are named and scoped within the sub-test.

The canonical example given in the link above seems to imply that the parameters used within the `with self.subtest()` clause can be passed as keyword arguments to `subTest()`.  For reference, the example shown is this:

```
class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_even(self):
        """
        Test that numbers between 0 and 5 are all even.
        """
        for i in range(0, 6):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
```

It is using an ambiguous convention of naming the inner-scoped variable the same as the parameter (`i=i`).  I took this to mean that keyword argument name is taken as the inner scoped variable name.  However, when I tried to create my own test, I found that both PyCharm and the python interpreter complained of unresolved references if the keyword argument was not named precisely the same as the outer-scoped variable used as the parameter input.

i.e.:

```
class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_even(self):
        """
        Test that numbers between 0 and 5 are all even.
        """
        for i in range(0, 6):
            with self.subTest(num=i):  # <-- Renamed keyword argument parameter
                self.assertEqual(num % 2, 0)  # < -- Results in unresolved reference error "num"
```

How does one pass parameters into the subtest?  How are they named and referenced within the subtest code block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be nice if this was expounded on a little bit more in the docs, but the [API for `subTest(msg=None, **params)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) states:

> ...msg and params are optional, arbitrary values which are displayed
> whenever a subtest fails, allowing you to identify them clearly.

So it seems that the keyword arguments passed in **params are used only for test identification when printing test status to the console.  They don't get passed in as parameters to the code block in any fashion.